# Paypal Integration with 2 payments within 1 transaction

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment

Our clients has an special paypal payment requirements.

I wanted to know if we can possible do 1 transaction and get the full amount then relay the 2% of the payment to the another paypal  account?

Answer (score 1):

Oh. Got the solution its called **Adaptive Payment**.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/